# cefsharp get html from js popup(iframe)

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I am using cefsharp in a project. I have a problem with this, I can not access the html code of the iframe js popup that opens inside the web site. Here is the code I used in the project.

```
private void WebBrowserFrameLoadEnded(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
 chromeBrowser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
{
                    var html = taskHtml.Result;
}
}
```

window.location code is used in the page that directs the popup. I guess I do not have access to the actual datum because it's routing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: FrameLoadEnd is called for every frame, you can get the source at a frame level using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IFrame_GetSourceAsync.htm the eventargs has a Frame property

Comment: @amaitland hi, Could you share sample code for popup? please :)

Comment: e.Frame.GetSourceAsync